# What does it mean to have a transmission coefficient 1.03*10^-3

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-tunneling, textbook-erratum

I solved a potential barrier problem. E=4.5ev
V0=5eV
barrier width a=950pm
The transmission coefficient came out to be 1.03*10^-3
I was wondering what this means? 
isn't the transmission probability too small?
I'm trying to visualise it on the graph given here
http://www.nano-ou.net/qmtunneling.aspx

Comment: prima facie the graphs do not match with your calculated value.

Comment: I think authors have made mistake in calculating the values, your calculations are right.

Comment: What do you mean "too small"?  A transmission probability can be any number between 0 and 1, and 1.03*10^-3 is within that range.  Or do you mean that your calculation does not agree with the graph in the link?

Comment: Is this about an electron tunnelling, need to know it's effective mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to make use of the natural units in the problem. Here the natural units are $eV$ for energy and $nm$ for distances (assuming this is an atomic problem).

If you look at the formula given in the link you have $$T=\frac{1}{1+ \left( \frac{K_2^2 + K_1^2}{2 K_1 K_2} \right)^2 \sinh^2 K_2a}$$ with $K_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2 m E}{\hbar^2}}, \, K_2 = \sqrt{\frac{2m(V_0-E)}{\hbar^2}}$ so that $\frac{K_2^2 + K_1^2}{K_1 K_2}$ can be written as $\frac{V_0}{\sqrt{E(V_0-E)}}$. With your numbers you have $\left( \frac{K_2^2 + K_1^2}{2 K_1 K_2} \right)^2 = \frac{V_0^2}{4 E (V_0 - E)} = \frac{25}{4 \times 4.5 \times 0.5} = \frac{25}{9}$ (since it is the ratio of two quantities with the same units it is a pure number). Now for $\sinh K_2 a$. Write $K_2 a = \left( \sqrt{\frac{2m (V_0-E)}{\hbar^2}} \right)a$ as $$\left( \sqrt{\frac{2mc^2 (V_0-E)}{\hbar^2 c^2}} \right)a = \left( \sqrt{\frac{2\frac{mc^2}{q} \frac{(V_0-E)}{q}}{ (\frac{\hbar c}{q})^2}}  \right) a .$$ The first step (multiply top and bottom by $c$, the speed of light), means that you can substitute for $m$ as $mc^2$, an energy, while the second step (dividing top and bottom by $1/q$ where $q$ is the charge on an electron) converts energies in $J$ to $eV$. So you need to substitute $\frac{m c^2}{q} = 0.5 MeV = 500 \, 000 eV$, $\frac{V_0 - E}{q} = 0.5 eV$. If you then look up $\frac{\hbar c}{q}$ you will find that it has the value $0.197 eV \mu m = 197 eV nm$ (since $1 \mu m = 1000 \, nm$. The factor in the bracket has the value $() = 3.589$ but the most important thing is that it has units $\frac{1}{nm}$. The width of your well is $a = 950 \, pm = 0.950 \, nm$ so that $K_2 a = 3.410$ and $\sinh K_2 a \approx 15.133$. This finally gives $T$ as $$T = \frac{1}{1+\frac{25}{9}\times 15.133^2}\approx 1.6 \times 10^{-3}.$$ This is close to what you get, but remember, this result has used the effective mass of the electron as $1$. In the graph you need to look at the results for $\frac{E}{V_0} = 0.9$ and $a= 1 \, nm$, but that figure has probably used the effective mass of the electron as $1$ and it will also depend on the depth of the well (rather than just on $\frac{E}{V_0}$).

Comment: I did not use the effective mass though, I just simply used the value known to us which is 9.11 × 10^-31 Kg. Also instead of eV i did the calculations in J itself. I does depend on the depth of well or in this case the height of the barrier. I got roughly the same result without using effective mass.